# Safari and Chrome placeholder texts are different

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

I just writing same code but looks like different. How can I solve this?

Note: I don't want to give extra width or decrease font size because it is not a solution for main problem. (Main problem is difference between placeholders.) I just changed the design but still want to know why they are different. If anyone knows please share with us. Thanks!

Safari Version (Placeholder Text, .com):
[image: Safari Version]

Chrome Version (Placeholder Text, .com):
[image]

Code:

```HTLM
<div className={styles.func_container}>
  <div className={styles.subscribe_container}>
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="johndoe@example.com"
      className={styles.text_input}
    />
    <div className={styles.button}>abone ol</div>
  </div>
  <div className={styles.contact_container}>
    <h1 className={styles.contact_text}>veya</h1>
    <a
      href="mailto:info@catoflow.com"
      className={`${styles.button} ${styles.blue}`}
    >
      bize ulaş
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.text_input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 580px;
  font-size: 54px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: var(--black);
  caret-color: var(--light-gray);
}

.text_input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-size: 54px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: var(--light-gray);
  opacity: 1;
}

.text_input::placeholder {
  font-size: 54px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: var(--light-gray);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: I tried give same letter-spacing, but it is not working :((

Comment: your placeholder doesn't do any good if it's very hard to read even for people with very good eyesight. https://www.levelaccess.com/blog/web-accessibility-overview/

Comment: Thank you, I will change color but problem is different.

Comment: please provide the html + CSS for this otherwise, we can't figure out the reason for this. With just an image given I'd say, just make the input a tiny bit wider, or the font a tiny bit smaller?

Comment: Not a solution for main problem. It will make also different placeholders or paddings.

Comment: I inspected in chrome and safari and discovered no significant differences in browser pre-styles. since it's only a few pixels you may have to consider my previous suggestion. I believe it's just sth that the browsers handle differently. Additionally there are not many CSS rules supported for `::placeholder` https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/57-styling-css-placeholder/#supported-styles

Comment: Looking good in Safari and Firefox, and bad in Chrome and Opera. One attribute must be different in placeholder.

Comment: it's common, the design of the fonts is different between Apple and the others. The origin of this difference dates back to the "Adobe war" which gave birth to trueType fonts. Adobe still jealously guards its graphics rendering algorithms, which forced Apple to completely reinvent them.

Comment: You have to allow for differences between browsers. Sometimes you have to compromise your ideal design to find a solution which works well enough across at least the major browsers.

Comment: If I were to do philosophy, I wouldn't be a web developer :(. It's like I'm trying to reconcile with my girlfriend. Anyway, I sincerely thank you for your help. I condemn the developer community for this difference.